# Автоматический сбор Rollup с SCSS

Tags: javascript, html, scss, rollup

Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой, есть у меня папка src, в ней лежит app.js и style.scss, в app.js импортирован style.scss, так же в src есть папка components, в ней лежит header.js и header.scss. Импортирую header.scss в style.scss и тут возникает такая проблема, меняю стили в header.scss, нажимаю сохранить и ничего не происходит, проект не пересобирается, для сборки требуется сохранять либо style.scss, либо же js файл. Пользуюсь Rollup, может кто подскажет, что нужно сделать что бы сборка шла, даже при сохранении стилей в header.scss или любых других scss файлах импортированных в style.scss?

вот настройки rollup.config

```
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';

export default {
    input: "src/app.js",
    output: {
        dir: "dist",
        format: "iife"
    },
    plugins: [
        scss({ fileName: 'bundle.css' }),
        nodeResolve(),
        babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled' }),
        serve({ open:true, contentBase: './', port:8000 }  ),
        livereload()
    ]
}
```

если еще что-то нужно отправить, для полноты картины, то подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, просто импортируем header.scss в header.js, а не в основной style.scss